# Old driver installing on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, drivers, developer-tools

I have a Roland SP 555 whose drivers are really old (https://www.roland.com/global/support/by_product/sp-555/updates_drivers/). With the driver you can play sounds on sp from your computer or vice versa. Someone has managed to make the driver work with Windows 10 but when it comes to Mac there aren't many options and I decided do it by myself.

The code is short and simple. I've made some changes and installer runs on Big Sur. Driver installs a plugin, a prefPane and a kext file to 3 different paths. Those paths are:

/Library/PreferencePanes/

/Library/Audio/MIDI Drivers

/System/Library/Extensions/

The first two are writeable but the 3rd folder has been made unwriteable with Big Sur. There are ways to easily walk around of it and make changes but I just couldn't find a way in Big Sur.

So how can i make this driver work on my mac? It's really important to me. How can I make this driver work by installing it to a different path?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to install the drivers in a Big Sur installation and it failed. Mainly because I am using a MacBook M1 and its ARM architecture didn't seem to like the installer

I did discover some interesting stuff that might be helpful for Intel based macs though.
I am gonna try to explain it, step by step, so you can do the same and test it out on your side.
I extracted the .pkg files so I can install them manually (the system/Library/extensions `.kext` too)

Here are the files [on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZjsB9Su1bx3IIyqq1lvHyG0hJirXzJE/view?usp=sharing).

1. Watch [this video first](https://youtu.be/4XS6Syno-2M)!
2. Reboot your Mac and enter in recovery mode.
   Open Terminal app and write:

   ```
   csrutil authenticated-root disable
   ```
3. Reboot your mac normally, install the downloaded files inside `HD/library/` and create a folder in `/users/yourname/` called "nonroot" (keep the files inside System for later)
4. Open terminal and write:

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```

   (this allows you to check the name of your main HD drive. Mine is disk3s1)
5. Write inside terminal:

   ```
   sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs /dev/disk3s1 ~/nonroot
   ```
6. Go to `users/yourname/` and you'll find your HD. Enter, and go to `System/Library/Extensions/` and put the `.kext` file inside.
7. Go to Terminal and write this to save the file. It will be there even if you reboot your Mac.

   ```
   sudo bless --folder ~/nonroot/System/Library/CoreServices --bootefi --create-snapshot
   ```
8. Reboot your computer and the extension should work.

In my M1 MacBook, I get a message saying that the extension failed at launch because it is not an arm extension. I hope this works for Intel Macs!

Let me know!